# Error en la parte de dependencias

Tags: android-studio

Estoy intentando hacer Google-Map en `Android Studio` pero me da error, me subraya esta linea:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
```

Ademas de eso me dice `RENDER PROBLEM`.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.itshareplus.googlemapdemo"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En realidad la linea que comentas es subrayada no es un error es un aviso (warning) indicando que preferentemente uses la misma versión de versiones, ya que tu  versión de la support library es `23.2.1` pero tu  `buildToolsVersion` es `25.0.0`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tu programa puede iniciarse pero podría provocar errores.

Puedes realizar este cambio, usar:

```
 compileSdkVersion 25
 buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
```

y

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

además usar solo la library de maps para no usar todo play services:

```
   //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
```

Comment: si gracias lo he solucionado con una combinacion de teclas ctrl +alt + chif+s para cambiar el api y otras pequeñas cosas   pero gracias